# AJAX parseerror after success handler is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-6

I have weird situations when using AJAX in jQuery.
I use node.js along with express.js on the backend side, here simple route that i wrote for my backend:

```
app.all('/*', (request, response, next) => {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,accept,access_token,X-Requested-With');
    next();
});

app.post('test', (request, response) => {
    response.json(
        {
            "message": "success", 
            "data" : "test"
        }
    );

    // I also tried to chain .status(200) before calling .json(), the problem still occur
});
```

now in the frontend, I use following code to perform request:

```
export class TestPage {
    constructor() {
        this._name = 'test';
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    performRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'localhost:15000/test',
            data: { "test": "nothing" },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and call the class from my main script like this:

```
   import { TestPage } from './TestPage'

   let test = new TestPage();
   test.performRequest();
```

Now after AJAX perform the request, it will trigger the success callback, however, error callback is triggered as well.

Here what i got from console window:
[image: Console Window]

As you might notice, the 1st log is come from success callback, the rest are come from error callback.

Any ideas what happening here and how to resolve this problem? thanks

**---- EDIT ----**
I found the source of errors, so in short I use babel in order to use ES6 features and I use class on the client side

if I move the request to constructor like:

```
export class TestPage {

    constructor() {
        this._name = 'test'
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'localhost:15000/test',
            data: { "test": "nothing" },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
let test = new TestPage();
```

It works! without error callback being called.

Now my question, how this can be happen? why? and how do i separate the request call to a function? calling request in constructor is not something that i wanted because probably I want to encapsulate the request somewhere in my class.

Comment: Are you saying both success and error callbacks are firing for one ajax? That should never happen. Those logs might be coming from different ajax requests.

Comment: I am agree with @Ozan,...  also try with function(){} instead of ()= >{}

Comment: Both come from one ajax, I tried to add some log to make sure it is come from one ajax also adding beforeSend parameters and log it, and indeed it come from one ajax request..

the before send also called once

Comment: @HareshVidja I try with function() {}, but the problem still persist

Comment: @lumine, try with my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue (I'm using babel.js to enable ES6), I doubt the code you posted here is your actual code.

But here my suggestions:

1. Make sure logs come from the corresponding ajax request, not from another request. (like being @Ozan said, double check it for sure)
2. Make sure your callback isn't throwing an error. (in case your actual code is different from this post)
3. Try to make a request on plan javascript.
4. Try to log the `request` object from the server side, maybe you will find something useful
5. A bit ugly but you can try to parse the response manually, remove `dataType: 'json'` and use `JSON.parse(response)` on client side to retrieve the JSON object, use `try-catch` block may helpful in case it fail to parse it.

But like @Ozan said, something like this should never happen, post your actual / full code in case it is different.

Comment: You;re right, I try to simplify things here, but for some reason, an error thrown in `success` callback, using `try catch` to detect the source of error and removing the corresponding codes fix the issue. Also, your 5th suggestion about parsing it manually works as well (even error is being thrown in `success` callback). Now it make sense, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

On node.js side code please try with response.send() instead of response.json()

```
app.post('test', (request, response) => {
    response.send({"message": "success","data" : "test"});
});
```